# facebook login how user retrieve user data with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, facebook-login

i try to get user id, name, e-mail.
my code working for loging in, and loging out. i get login name, but something missing. 
why not work response.e-mail or response.id when i change with response.name
test api working but i need e mail and user id pls help

```
 function testAPI() {   
      FB.api('/me', function (response) {       
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = response.name ;
      });
  }
```

here is my login button code :

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState(); data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-show-faces="true" data-auto-logout-link="true"">
</fb:login-button>

<div id="status">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved problem. i hope it will help someone 
here is my working codes:

```
  function testAPI() {   
      FB.api('/me', 'GET', { "fields": "id,name,picture,email" }, function (response) {
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = response.email ;
      });
  }
```